# Projectional skeletons in dual Banach algebras

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

A Banach algebra $A$ is a *dual Banach algebra* if it is a dual Banach space with a (not necessarily unique) predual $A_{\ast}$, and the multiplication on $A$ is separately weak*-continuous. Dual Banach algebras are naturally analogous to von Neumann algebras [[Daws2007](https://doi.org/10.4064/sm178-3-3), [Daws2011](https://doi.org/10.3318/PRIA.2011.111.1.3)]; thus, one may expect a given dual Banach algebra to possess a rich structured subset of idempotents. (e.g., structured as explained in [[Laustsen2003](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0017089502008947), [DawsHorvath2021](https://doi.org/10.4153/S0008414X20000565)] )

**Question:** Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and $A\subseteq B(E)$ be a dual Banach algebra. Does $A$ contain *projectional skeletons*  (e.g. [[Kubis2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2008.07.006)] ) or *projectional resolutions of identity* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $A = \ell_\infty$ is a dual Banach algebra. Every separable complemented subspace of $A$ is finite-dimensional, so there is no way to exhaust $A$ by nicely complemented separable subspaces.

Comment: I should have phrased the problem more carefully & to the point. What if $A$ acts irreducibly on $E$? Equivalently, how does the set of the projections in the range of weak*-continuous irreducible representations of a dual Banach algebra look like?

Comment: @OnurOktay, that does not change anything. You can apply almost the same argument to $B(\ell_2)$, as every complemented separable subspace of it is reflexive.

Comment: Let me ask at least one meaningful question: If $A$ is reflexive or has Radon-Nikodym property, or weakly compactly generated, then $A$ admits a projectional skeleton (from your answer to a previous post, and from a reference of Fabian's journal article you've given a link to). These seemed a bit too restrictive for dual Banach algebras, however obviously I could not relax these extra conditions properly. What can be a reasonable Banach space property that guarantees the existence of projection skeletons? I apologize the question is way too general and not to the point.

Comment: @OnurOktay, being a Vašák space is probably the best you can think of.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02558

Comment: $\ell^{\infty}$ does not have projections with separable range, however unsurprisingly has a rich set of idempotents. Could we consider the same question as above by only replacing "separable range" in the definition of projectional skeleton by "ranges with dimension $\leq dens(A)$" ?

Comment: @OnurOktay, I guess then it trivialies to $\{{\rm id}_{\ell_\infty}\}$ being a PRI in your sense.

Comment: One aims to choose a PRI as small as possible, however I had in mind to look for the biggest set of projections possible since the beginnig. This caused the unclarity. Even though I enjoy this exchange (we can continue in the chat if you'd like) it is not considerate to waste your time.  I should perhaps spend more time thoroughly to fix the gaps until I come up with something really meaningful in this context. Thanks for all again.

Answer (score 0):

This note is not intended as an answer but rather a long comment.
I realize I asked the wrong question as soon as I see Tomasz Kania's answer. So I feel indebted to explain where I am trying to get with this post for everyone. I organize what I have in mind in a numbered list for the sake of clarity and brevity:

1. I would rather like to consider maximal commuting sets of projections than merely PRIs. The purpose here to establish a link with the usual ordering of projections.
2. Since a dual Banach algebra $A$ has a faithful representation on a reflexive Banach space $E$, then every irreducible representation $\pi$ of $A$ is equivalent to a representation on a reflexive Banach space. The reflexivity of the underlying Banach space $E$ provides us with a rich set of idempotents when $E$ is *non-separable*. Perhaps it is relevant to consider the commuting sets of projections with separable range that are contained in $\pi(A)$.
3. I think it is interesting to consider the minimum density of complemented subalgebras of non-reflexive dual Banach algebras for its own sake.
4. When $A$ is a reflexive Banach algebra, it is natural to consider $A$ as a subalgebra of $B(A)$ via the left regular representation. Perhaps it is relevant to consider the set of projections $P:A\to A$ with separable range that is contained in $A$. Similarly, let $L\subseteq A$ be a maximal modular left ideal and $E=A/L$. Clearly $E$ is reflexive and the reduction of the left regular representation $\pi:A\to B(E)$ is an irreducible representation. It is perhaps relevant to consider the set of projections $P:E\to E$ with separable range that is contained in $\pi(A)$.
5. Incorporating Banach space properties seems to be more delicate. Every C$^{\ast}$-algebra has property (V) and every von Neumann algebra is a Grothendieck space. Consequently, every quotient of a C$^{\ast}$-algebra is either reflexive (actually a Hilbert space) or contains a copy of $c_0$. Infinite dimensional Von Neumann algebras do not contain complemented copies of $c_0$, and their preduals contain complemented copies of $\ell^1$. On the other hand, not every dual Banach algebra has to have property (V) -- indeed, if a Banach algebra has property (V), then it is Arens regular. There are reflexive Banach spaces $E$ for which $B(E)$ is not a Grothendieck space, e.g.[[Kania2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2012.12.017)]. Thus, we do not have counterparts of these results for a general dual Banach algebra in this generality.
6. The predual $\mathcal{U}_{\ast}$ of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{U}$ has DPP iff $\mathcal{U}$ is type I finite. $\mathcal{U}_{\ast}$ has RNP iff $\mathcal{U}$ is atomic, i.e., the identity is a sum of minimal projections. $\mathcal{U}_{\ast}$ has Schur property iff $\mathcal{U}$ is type I finite and atomic. I think it is interesting to see the counterparts of these for dual Banach algebras with minimal extra hypotheses possible on the algebra. Thus, it is worthwhile to consider the structure of the set of idempotents in a dual Banach algebra when its predual has DPP and/or RNP.

In summary, it is a natural direction to explore the counterparts of some of the well-known results in von Neumann algebras for the dual Banach algebras. It is my expectation/prediction that the stem, which will grow from the previous research (examples of which are the articles with the links in the question body above), will eventually evolve a branch in this direction.

The simplest case to consider in this frame is the reflexive unital Banach algebras. This is the reason why I've posted a few questions in Mathoverflow about them.

Comment: PS: Banach algebras that are duals or preduals of C*-algebras (e.g. the measure algebra $M(G)$, the Fourier algebra $A(G)$ and the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra $B(G)$ of Harmonic analysis) are well-understood in terms of their Banach space properties.

Comment: What's the relevance of the Daws-Horvath paper on Dedekind finiteness of ultraproducts to what you are saying about DBAs?

Comment: @YemonChoi Sir, to the best of my limited knowledge, there are only a few papers about the (in)finiteness of the Banach algebras (specifically) $B(X)$, starting with Laustsen in 2003, and ending with Daws & Horvath in 2021 in chronological order. Isn't (in)finiteness about the structure of the set of idempotents? I intended to give Daws & Horvath paper as a representative only, even though they don't specifically mention DBAs or Banach space properties of the algebras & their ultraproducts.

Comment: @YemonChoi There are many experts in Banach spaces and Banach algebras in this medium like yourself, whose expertise is reflected by their published work. I consider myself an amateur and a life-long student in this field. Therefore, I would like to hear your perspective about what is missing, what is reasonable, etc.

Comment: I agree that "it is a natural direction to explore the counterparts of some of the well-known results in von Neumann algebras for the dual Banach algebras" but I don't remember this being the perspective of Daws and Horvath in that paper. My point is that I don't think the DBA perspective plays a role there, so if your interest here is about DBAs then mentioning their paper seems like a red herring. However I have not looked at their paper recently so perhaps I overlooked something.

Comment: The key thing to remember is that in both Cstar and vN-algebraic settings, a key ingredient that is needed throughout all the structure theory is that commutative Cstar algebras have a very special form, and commutative von Neumann algebras are even more special or restricted. In the general DBA setting, since the class of all Fourier-Stieltjes algebras is already too wild to describe completely, one is going to need extra assumptions in order to get anything like the structure theory for von Neumann algebras

Comment: @YemonChoi I agree that $A(G)$ and $B(G)$ are already too wild to describe completely. Let me exemplify what I mean: $A(G)$ has RNP iff the regular representation of $G$ is atomic. $B(G)$ has RNP iff every unitry representation of $G$ is atomic iff $C^{\ast}(G)$ contains no copy of $\ell^1$ iff $C^{\ast}(G)$ is scattered. $B(G)$ has Schur property iff $C^{\ast}(G)$ is contains no copy of $\ell^1$ and has DPP iff $C^{\ast}(G)$ is scattered and all irred. repn.'s are finite dimensional iff $G$ is compact.

Comment: These characterizations use the properties of $C^{\ast}(G)$, $W^{\ast}(G)$ and their reduced counterparts $C_r^{\ast}(G)$, $VN(G)$.

Comment: Sure, I am not disputing that there are interesting things to be investigated regarding the Banach space geometry of various DBAs and their preduals. My point is that you mentioned the Daws-Horvath paper, and my original comment was meant to ask which parts of that were supposed to be relevant to the questions you are asking.

Comment: You wrote "it is a natural direction to explore the counterparts of some of the well-known results in von Neumann algebras for the dual Banach algebras. There is an ongoing research (e.g. see [DawsHorvath2021] and the references therein)". I am questioning whether the second sentence is really related to the first sentence

Comment: @YemonChoi I must admit it is my expectation/prediction that this paper and a few previous ones will evolve a branch in this direction. Perhaps I should have mentioned instead Laustsen's 2003 article about in/finiteness of the algebras of bounded operators $B(X)$.

Comment: I see. I am still not convinced that the Daws-Horvath paper is relevant. Note that concepts such as finiteness and proper/pure infiniteness do not require any kind of weak-star topology and indeed are nowadays mostly studied in the Cstar setting not the von Neumann setting. Hence I must confess that mentioning that paper here just looks like a bit of a red herring. (Also note that B(X) is a DBA if and only if X is reflexive, so several of the examples in NJL's 2003 paper cannot be DBAs)

Comment: @YemonChoi I've just edited the red herring out, thanks for the heads up. It's true that duality, thus the weak* topology, is not required in Daws-Horvath paper. Surely Laustsen's 2003 article contains examples for non-reflexive $X$, while its results apply to reflexive $X$ as well, e.g. Corollaries 1.5 & 1.9.

Comment: Even the most familiar C*-algebras may lack enough projections. Type classifications don't even require projections but abelian elements, e.g. type I C*-algebras. However, equivalent definitions provide projection rich settings, e.g. the bidual being type I VN-algebra, or the irreducible representations being type I. Starting from here, isn't it reasonable to take advantage of the projection-rich non-separable reflexive Banach spaces $E$ to classify DBAs $A\subseteq B(E)$?

Comment: Having that said, perhaps DBAs with irreducible representations on (necessarily separable) reflexive HI Banach spaces have a special place. I treasure your insight & opinion about what can be done.